# How to bind event listener if not previously set before with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Somewhere in my code I execute this:

```
function hook(el) {
    console.log("hooked")
}

$('a[href!="#"]').click(hook)
```

I would like to prevent accidentally to reset the hook because if I execute again:

```
$('a[href!="#"]').click(hook)
```

Whoops, I'll get twice `hooked`. Is there a way to look if `hook` was already associated with the `onclick` event?

The context behind this is the following:

```
function hook(e) {
    let uri = e.currentTarget.pathname

    e.preventDefault();

    if (uri == window.location.pathname)
        return;

    $.get(uri, function (data) {
        data = $(data)

        let main = data.find('#main').html()

        if (!main) {
            window.location.href = uri
            return
        }

        $('#main').html(main)

        install() // Reinstall the hook for the new code

        if (history.pushState) {
            history.pushState({'main': main }, null, uri);
        }
    }).fail(function () {
        window.location.href = uri
    });

    return false;
}

function install() {
    $('a[href!="#"]').click(hook);
}
```

Of course in this context I would solve the issue by only reinstalling the hook for the new code like something like `installOn($('#main'))`

Comment: We need more context into how/when you are doing this.  Otherwise the generic answer is "use a delegate only once"

Comment: Is this a one time deal for all links are just whatever was  clicked?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent future clicks on teh same element or prevent hook from being called more than once?

Comment: @basic he's trying to prevent duplicate bindings

Comment: Ok, so the links are in the #main?

Comment: @Taplar yes I am indeed trying to prevent duplicate bindings

Comment: @Taplar, the links could be everywhere

Comment: Then I would suggest you bind on those not in main outside of the ajax, and in the ajax, only bind on those that are in the main, as that is what is changing.

Comment: @Taplar Yeah this is a solution to this particular case, but It does not answer how to prevent duplicate bindings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function hook(e) {
    let uri = e.currentTarget.pathname

    e.preventDefault();

    if (uri == window.location.pathname)
        return;

    $.get(uri, function (data) {
        data = $(data)

        let main = data.find('#main').html()

        if (!main) {
            window.location.href = uri
            return
        }

        $('#main').html(main)

        // pass in the main context so it only binds on those
        install('#main') // Reinstall the hook for the new code

        if (history.pushState) {
            history.pushState({'main': main }, null, uri);
        }
    }).fail(function () {
        window.location.href = uri
    });

    return false;
}

function install(parentSelector) {
                   // find the elements in the context, or the document
    $('a[href!="#"]', parentSelector || document).click(hook);
}

//this will bind on all the links that match any where in the document
install();
```

Duplicate bindings are avoided with this solution by searching the desired context.

`install()` will target all matching elements as no context is passed in, so the install method defaults to finding all elements in the document.

In the ajax, `$('#main').html(main)` replaces the contents of the main with new elements.  Those elements are guarenteed to not have any bindings on them as `main` is a string, so the elements are created brand new.

Then, `install('#main')` **only** targets the elements inside the main, which are unbound, and puts the bindings on them.

So duplicate bindings are avoided.

Comment: @nowox comments added.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery allows the use of [event namespaces.](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/)

```
$('a[href!="#"]').on("click.hook", hook)
```

And then when you want to recreate and add the event again simply do so manually:

```
$('a[href!="#"]').off("click.hook");
$('a[href!="#"]').on("click.hook", hook);
```

Comment: @Taplar Actually, you're wrong. a click event does match a `click.namespace` event. http://jsfiddle.net/ka3eg6L7/

Comment: Iiiiiinteresting.  The api doesn't really make that very clear.  Nice catch.

Comment: @Taplar no worries. You caught me off guard because I haven't used JQuery in a bit so I thought maybe it had changed, then I made a fiddle initially with a bug in it so I assumed you were correct. haha. I definitely get how the documentation(which is normally really, really clear) could have brought you to your conclusion :)

Comment: Now I'm tempted to clone the api repo and try to get a pull request with that info added, :D